# How to use the word "magistricide"?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, neologisms

I’m having a bit of trouble using the word *magistricide* in context. I’m leaning towards using the word *suicide* as reference, but I’m still not sure if it’s correct.

So given the model of “a failed suicide”  or “a successful suicide”, 
does the model hold true for any *-cide* word, like *magistricide*?

- After another failed magistricide attempt, Bob . . . .
- After another failed attempt at magistricide, Bob . . . .
- After another failed attempt of magistricide, Bob . . . .

or

- After attempting magistricide, Bob . . . .

or

- The master noticed Bob’s failed magistricide attempt.
- The master noticed Bob’s failed attempt at magistricide.
- The master noticed Bob’s failed attempt of magistricide.

What version is correct or more common? The first? Or are all of them wrong?

Comment: Even Wiktionary concedes that _magistricide_ is a rarely used word. Other than in sentences like the previous one, usage would be 'quirky' or 'rarefied'.

Comment: All of them are grammatically correct, I think, though using "of" sounds a bit strange to me. None of them are common. If neither the (online) oxford dictionaries nor the (online) merriam-webster recognize a word my feeling is you really should attempt to use a different one.

Comment: In general, if you can find a word in Wiktionary/UrbanDictionary or any other crowdsourced word list but [not in any credible professional dictionary](http://i.imgur.com/6SKCNjc.jpg), that's an indication that the word was probably invented by someone on the Internet and hasn't seen widespread use or currency. In that case, there's not going to be a lot of prior usage to guide you or advice others can give you. My best advice is for preposition and sentence-construction purposes, treat the word like a u other *-cide* word (e.g. *homicide*).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth that's true, but it's also exactly the reason why I choose the word - since it's used in context within an "oldish"/medieval scenery.

Comment: @DanBron makes a good point, in that it would be better to use homicide or patricide as a reference word, instead of suicide, since they are closer in meaning to magistricide. Mainly in the sense that both of those are acts committed on someone else. My guess would be that magistricide originated from patricide (in the sense that someone knew patricide existed and figured "how can I use one word to describe the killing of a teacher/master so it sounds cool").

Comment: @Katai In that case you probably want words that were in use in "oldish"/medieval times as opposed to newly minted internet words. I have not been able to find any citation of magistricide older then 2009. Doesn't mean there isn't one obviously.

Comment: Actually my bad there seems to be one usage from 1630 by R.Lassels but that is used as a noun (proper) in the title of "Nero the Magistricide" and is in a book written about Italy (thus might be a translation from a latin text where someone uses the name).

Comment: It's an odd word, but I would think you would use it just as you use "homicide".

Comment: @DRF thanks for the clarification. I just assumed that the word itself was real / used - especially because of words like patricide and homicide. I didn't realize that it was apparently a current "invention" because it seemed logical to exist ;)

Comment: @DanBron I presume the OED will suffice? :)

Comment: @Dan: in general, if you can find a word, then it was most definitely invented.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Empenchanting flotsoftly ergasive prum!

Comment: @HotLicks Columbanus, the renowned magistricide detective.

Comment: *As an English word, [**magistricide**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22magistricide+is+dismissed+by+the+Oxford+English+Dictionary%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is dismissed by the Oxford English Dictionary as a nonce-formation (by analogy with 'parricide') of the 17th century, recorded only once, in Richard Lassels's The Voyage of Italy (Paris 1670)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Magisterial Coinage

All your uses are fine as they go, but the last set is clearest because of how uncommon a word *magistricide* is. On the other hand, it is solidly built of well-established parts, so it would be immediately recognizable to any educated reader.

You would not be the first to use *magistricide*, for this is a rather old word, not a newly minted one as some have suggested.  From the OED:

> ### *maˈgistricide*. *nonce-wd*.
>
> Etymology: f. as if L. **magistricīda* (after *parricīda*, etc.: see *-cide* <sup>1</sup>), f. *magister* master.
>
> A murderer of one’s master or teacher.
>
> - 1670 Lassels *Voy. Italy II.* 172 ― Nero the Magistricide, who put this rare man his master to death.

Notice the OED calls it a nonce word: a word crafted for one particular use at one particular time and used just that once. Apparently the 1670 citation is not wholly unique, which makes it more of a rare word than a nonce word.  Still, even if it is rare, it is perfectly clear in its meaning.

Even if your word **were** actually freshly minted, it is a only natural to form new words based on old models. That’s how language works. Indeed, the *‑cide* component has been used time and time again to form new nouns, and sometimes adjectives,  that work like *suicide* and *homicide*  — which, by the way, are the only two that have come into common use as verbs not just as nouns.

Here are some 126 *‑icide* words mentioned in the OED:

> *acaricide, algicide, aliicide, apricide, arboricide, avicide, bacillicide,
>   bactericide, bioinsecticide, biopesticide, bovicide, Brahminicide,
>   canicide, cervicide, ceticide, Christicide, coquicide, culicicide,
>   cyanicide, deericide, deicide, dominicide, elephanticide, episcopicide,
>   famicide, felicide, femicide, feminicide, feticide, fideicide, filicide,
>   floricide, foeticide, fratricide, fungicide, gallicide, gallinicide,
>   gelicide, germicide, giganticide, gregicide, herbicide, hereticide,
>   hericide, homicide, hospiticide, hosticide, hymnicide, infanticide,
>   insecticide, lapicide, larvicide, legicide, leporicide, liberticide,
>   libricide, lignicide, macrofilaricide, macropicide, magistricide,
>   matricide, menticide, microbicide, mildewicide, miticide, modernicide,
>   molluscicide, monstricide, muricide, mycoherbicide, naticide, nematicide,
>   neonaticide, omnicide, ovicide, oxyuricide, paracide, parasiticide,
>   parenticide, parricide, patricide, perdricide, pesticide, philosophicide,
>   piggicide, piscicide, politicide, populicide, prolicide, raticide,
>   ratticide, regicide, regnicide, rodenticide, schizonticide, self-homicide,
>   senicide, serpenticide, siblicide, silicide, silvicide, sororicide,
>   spermaticide, spermicide, stillicide, stiricide, suicide, taeni(i)cide,
>   talpicide, tauricide, temporicide, tickicide, tsaricide, tyrannicide,
>   urbicide, ursicide, utricide, uxoricide, vaccicide, vaticide, verbicide,
>   vermicide, verminicide, viricide, vulpicide,* and *weedicide.*

There are also a few *‑ocide* words:

> *biocide, ecocide, ethnocide, genocide, Negrocide, phytocide, pseudocide, spermatocide, trypanocide,* and *tuberculocide*.

What all that shows is that people are rather fond of coining new *‑cide* words. I find many of those listed **significantly *less* recognizable** than your *magistricide*, and I feel that some of them work better than others. For example, why someone would elect *weedicide* over *herbicide*, I have no earthly idea. *Piggicide* is another ungainly and unfortunate term, but I suppose they must have feared that *suidicide* might be confused for *suicide*.

Nonetheless, I would suggest using *magistricide* in a context where the connection between *master* and *magister* were made eminently clear, such as in the Lassels citation or indeed in your own final proffered set of sentences:

> - The **master** noticed Bob’s failed **magistricide** attempt.
> - The **master** noticed Bob’s failed attempt at **magistricide**.
> - The **master** noticed Bob’s failed attempt of **magistricide**.

As with the Lassels, by using both the current English word and the learnèd Latinate one together, you gently remind your reader of the connection between them.

Comment: Note that there are two slightly different paradigms in these *-cide* words: some of them (*homicide, regicide*) mean "the act of killing" (*Joe is guilty of homicide*) or, more archaically, a person who kills (*Macbeth was a regicide*); but others (*pesticide, herbicide*) mean "a substance that kills".  In this case it should be clear from context that *magistricide* would be the former, unless you were being jocular (*he put magistricide in his teacher's coffee*).

Comment: There's an old joke exploiting this ambiguity: "Why did the ant spray himself with Raid? He wanted to commit insecticide."

Comment: It's certainly quite interesting to get a bit more background on the other "-cide" words! I have one minor questions, more as a side note though: Of those last 3 quoted sentences with Bob - which one would you personally pick? I'ld go with the first version again - i.e. "failed magistricide attempt"

Comment: @katai I think I might use *failed attempt at magistricide* so I could end the sentence with a strong word.